# mounting on boot - how to edit

Tags: linux, boot, partition

How does linux know which partition should be mounted at which directory? Where is this info stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information about what hard drives to mount where is stored in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: And the current mount information is in `/etc/mtab`

Comment: ...or in /proc/mounts, /etc/mtab is some cases may have wrong info

Answer (score 1):

Your search for which partition is mounted may not end in fstab, the listing may use LABELs or UUIDs.  You can search for LABELs with e2label.